# Showing the list of pull_requests on the homepage

Tags: django, sqlite

I have a model Pull_Requests in my database that's containing data and I want to display this data into an HTML table on my homepage. So I created the view, urls and home files as they are below but I'm getting nothing when I run the app. As I am new in this area, I'm not able to detect what could be the issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

class home(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'  

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        pull_requestsList = Pull_Requests.objects.all()
        pullRequest_dict = {'pull_requests': pull_requestsList}
        return render(request, self.template_name, pullRequest_dict)

    from django.urls import path from. import views
        urlpatterns = [
                path('', views.home, name='home'),
            ]

    % extends "base.html" %}
    {% load static %}

     {% block body %}
           <div class="container">
                {% if pullrequests %}
                    {% for field in pullrequests %}
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ field.pr_project  }}</th>
                                <th>{{ field.pr_id }} </th>
                                <th>{{ field.nd_comments }} </th>
                                <th>{{ field.nb_added_lines_code }}</th>
                                <th>{{ field.nb_deleted_lines_code }}</th>
                                <th>{{ field.nb_commits }}</th>
                                <th>{{ field.nb_changed_fies }}</th>
                                <th>{{ field.Closed_status }}</th>
                                <th>{{ field.reputation }}</th>
                                <th>{{ field.Label }}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <strong> There is no pull request in the database. </strong>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You've only shown part of the code. Where is the rest of the view class that get_queryset belongs to? And what are the patterns in urls.py?

Comment: Don't post code as comments, it is unreadable. Edit the question and post your code there. And where is the URL that actually points to that view?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Sir, are you checking, please?

Comment: I can't really understand this code, I'm afraid. Is the indentation right? Is Pull_RequestView really nested inside `home`?

Comment: I think is home. Or you can suggest something that can work because I really don't know how does it work. Everything turns around home but as I don't how it works that my code looks like a mess. Thanks

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Have you really nested Pull_RequestView inside home, or is it just a problem with the indentation in posting the question here?

Comment: Oh yeah, this is an indentation problem. sorry I didn't see that.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, is there any hope or should I forget it, please?

Comment: Of course there's hope, this is a very simple thing to do. But I can't help you until you fix your question. *Where* is the indentation error - just here on SO, or in your actual code? Can you fix it in both places? And post the URL that you want to use?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman,  I've already updated my question. Please have a look. Hope it is understandable now.

Comment: `get_queryset` is supposed to return a queryset, not render a template.

Comment: Sorry, Sir, I don't have enough reputation for the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues.

The main problem is that `get_queryset` is supposed to return a queryset, not render a template. Because you do not return a queryset, and don't set the `model` attribute on the view, Django has no way of knowing what type of objects you're intending to list and therefore doesn't create a `pullrequests` object in the template context.

That method isn't doing anything useful anyway; you should probably just remove it, and define the attribute instead. So your view is literally just:

```
class home(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'  
    model = Pull_Requests
```

But note also that the name Django creates will be `pull_requests_list`, so you should use that in your template. (Also also, you don't need the `if` block; the `for` loop has an `empty` clause.) So:

```
{% block body %}
       <div class="container">
            {% for field in pull_requests_list %}
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ field.pr_project  }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.pr_id }} </th>
                        <th>{{ field.nd_comments }} </th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_added_lines_code }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_deleted_lines_code }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_commits }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_changed_fies }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.Closed_status }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.reputation }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.Label }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            {% empty %}
                <strong> There is no pull request in the database. </strong>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```